# If Else statement causes strage behaviour GLSL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So my vertex shader goes something like this

```
String vertexshader = "#version 330 core"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "in vec4 vertexin;"
        + "in vec2 textcoords;"
        + "in int texture;"
        + "uniform mat4 orthogonal;"
        + "out vec2 supertextcoords;"
        + "out int textureoi;"
        + "void main(){"
        + "gl_Position = orthogonal * vertexin ;"
        + "supertextcoords = textcoords;"
        + "textureoi=texture;"
        + "}";
```

And my fragment shader goes something like this

```
String fragmentshader="#version 330 core"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        +"out vec4 outcolor;"
        + "in int textureoi;"
        +"in vec2 supertextcoords;"
        +"uniform sampler2D texture1;"
        +"uniform sampler2D texture2;"
        + "vec4 texturedecode();"
        + "vec4 texturedecode() {"
        + "vec4 color;"
        + "if(textureoi==0) {"
        + "color= texture2D(texture1, supertextcoords); return color; }"
        + "else if(textureoi==1) {"
        + " color= texture2D(texture2, supertextcoords); return color;"
        + "} else {"
        + " color= texture2D(texture2, supertextcoords); return color;}"
        + "}"
        +"void main(){"         
        +" outcolor =texturedecode();"      
        +"}";
```

The problem is that when I glUseProgram() I get error 1282. The problem only happens if I use the function texturedecode(). It does not matter if I use it on the outcolor variable or on its own declaring some unused variable. It crashes opengl.

The way I send the variables is as follows.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureInit.loadTexture(io.getSubimage(0,0, 32, 32), 4));
int loc1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture1");
glUniform1i(loc1, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureInit.loadTexture(io.getSubimage(32,0, 32, 32), 4));
int loc2 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture2");
glUniform1i(loc2, 0);
int orthographicloc=glGetUniformLocation(program,"orthogonal");
glUniformMatrix4(orthographicloc,false, orthographicBuffer);
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertexin");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "textcoords");  
glLinkProgram(program);


glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT,false,0,0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,false,0,vertices.length*datasize);
glVertexAttribIPointer(2,1,GL_INT,0,vertices.length*datasize+textcoord.length*4);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length/4);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Comment: any log error while compiling/linking the shader?

Comment: No errors whatsoever after compiling and linking. Only after I use glUseProgram(). And then everything after that goes 1282.

Comment: You probably wouldn't get the desired result anyway because you're setting both texture uniforms to the same value (0). But that doesn't explain the error.

Comment: Thats a good catch. I changed the second one to glUniform1i(loc2, 1); Like you mentioned this did not help. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: You're also binding two vertex attributes to the same location. Both `vertexin` and `outcolor` are bound to location 0. Not that it would change anything, because you're making the `glBindAttribLocation()` calls after linking the program. That might actually be your real problem.

Comment: Changed and it still does not work. I moved all those glBindAttribLocation() calls before glLinkProgram(), then I removed the call to bind outcolor because I didnt use it anyways. Still 1282 all over the place. Editted question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There we go! The problem was that the integer was not "flat". What does this mean? I have no idea. But the way to solve this is to write

```
flat out int textureoi;
```

and

```
flat in int textureoi;
```

Comment: The syntax of those statements didn't quite look right. I edited it, please verify that it's correct. Anyway, `flat` means that the variable is not interpolated, and remains constant across triangles. It's required for integer type variables. From the spec: "Fragment shader inputs that are signed or unsigned integers or integer vectors must be qualified with the interpolation qualifier flat."

Comment: Thank you. Would have never caught that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Non-uniform_flow_control):

> In fragment shaders, there is one other circumstance that can cause all of your non-"Lod" or "Grad" texture accesses to become undefined: non-uniform flow control.
>
> Uniform flow control for a particular location in code means that, no matter how a shader is executed, the shader will follow the same path to get to that location of code. Consider the following GLSL code for a fragment shader:

```
void main()
{
  vec4 firstData = texture(someSampler, textureCoords);

  if(parameterValue < 20)
  {
      firstData += texture(someOtherSampler, otherTexCoords);
  }

  vec4 moreData = texture(thirdSampler, thirdTexCoords);
}
```

> The first texture access happens in uniform flow control. Thus, the texture access produces definite results. However, the next texture access is not in uniform flow. If the accessed texture uses mipmapping or anisotropic filtering of any kind, then any texture function that is not "Lod" or "Grad" will retrieve undefined results. The last texture access happens in uniform flow control again and will produce definite results.
>
> Note: The GLSL compiler will not give you an error for this. It is perfectly legal GLSL code. It only becomes undefined when certain texture state is set on those textures. Specifically, if mipmap or anisotropic filtering is used.

To mitigate this, you can either sample both textures and use the if/else to return the appropriate color value, or use `textureGrad` manually.

Comment: Okay so I checked this out and I decided to just leave it and write this as my output no matter what else happens in the shader           + "outcolor=texture2D(texture2, supertextcoords);" And that still gave 1282. Why? This is outside any if/else , for, while. Nothing should effect it yet... 1282.

Comment: The problem goes away only if I remove all control structure.

Comment: 1282 = `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, which can be caused by a ton of things. If your driver supports KHR_debug, you can register a callback to get a hopefully more descriptive error message.

Comment: I didn't find anything yet but could I get back to you later? I am going to learn how to use KHRdebug and then try it since my card supports it.